# What do “levels of interleaving” and “interleaved routines” mean?

Tags: c

I am reading documentation about software coding rules, and I do not understand the following English terms:

- levels of interleaving.
- interleaved routines.

Those terms are used in the following sentences:
“For maintainability (and to improve performance), C functions must not have more than 6 levels of interleaving.”

“A complex function is difficult to test. If a function contains 15 interleaved routines, there are 2<sup>15</sup> (or 32768) different branches to be checked in a single function!”

Please, could you explain to me what these terms mean?
An example would be useful.

Comment: I *think* it means nesting, like nested levels of `if` and `for` etc.

Comment: What is that document? I've never heard the term of " interleaved routine".

Comment: It's an internal document. Not available online. Some of the coding rules are based on MISRA C.

Comment: If it is an internal document, ask the author or the person responsible for maintaining it.

Comment: unfortunatly, that's not possible anymore.